# How to find peaks in a binary image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have this binary image, I would like to find peaks using findpeaks function.[image]

How do i go about doing it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract the 1D signal plotted there, and then apply `findpeaks`?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use [`findpeaks`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) with an image.

However, you can extract the data plotted in the image, and apply `findpeaks` on that. To extract the data, we first threshold to avoid very low gray values introduced in the image by the JPEG compression. This threshold leads to an image with only 0 and 1 values. Next, we find the first index in each column that contains a 1 value using [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html). Because images have the origin at the top left, rather than the bottom left as (I assume) the plotted data uses, we invert these indices.

```matlab
a = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1f5L.jpg');
a = a > 30; % some suitable threshold -- JPEG compression makes this necessary
a(end,:) = 1;
[~,b] = max(a,[],1);
b = size(a,1) - b; % reverse, origin is on the bottom of the image
[c,d] = findpeaks(b);
plot(b)
hold on
plot(d,c,'o')
axis equal
xlim([0,size(a,2)])
ylim([0,size(a,1)])
```

[image: plot of data in image, with local maxima highlighted]